# keep CentOS 7 from sleeping

Tags: centos, networking, sleep

Several CentOS 7 servers recently went to sleep when their internet connection went down.  They are all connected to a local network, and the connection between the outside internet and the local network's firewall was reset outside the local network.  When this happened, the CentOS 7 servers went to sleep.

**What specific commands or config can be used to cause CentOS 7 to NEVER sleep?**

Comment: What do you mean with "went to sleep"? Was the hardware hibernated? Or just network down? Did it respond to keyboard input?
CentOS doesn't just randomly "go to sleep". I guess it may be more a HW issue rather than CentOS.

Comment: @MLu The CentOS 7 servers in the network have remained "awake" reliably for their entire lifetimes of several months.  Then recently, when the local network was disconnected from the internet, all of the CentOS 7 machines stopped responding to local network `ping` and `http` requests.  We also could not `ssh` into them or even manually type commands into them using keyboards attached to each physical box.  The only way to get them to respond again was to press the power button on the physical boxes, which caused the operating systems to reboot.  The OP asks how to avoid this situation.

Comment: that's very unusual - it never happened to me and I run heaps of RHEL7 and CentOS7 servers. Do you know after how long after the network failure it happend? Can you reproduce it? I.e. if you unplug one of the servers from network will it "go to sleep" again after a while? What do you run on the servers? Perhaps some clustering software that may have decided that the connectivity to the rest of the cluster has failed and to be safe it shut down the machine? Is there something in the logs (e.g. `/var/log/messages`)?